# Where should the OAUTH2.0 Server be for Actions on Google/Firebase

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

Referring to - https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow Im using Actions SDK which implies Im using Firebase Functions for the fulfillment handling.

Im storing information in Firebase against the UID I got from FirebaseUser.getUid() in an Android app. So far so good.

I've setup a mock OAuth2.0 server and this seems to be happy exchanging tokens.

However later on in the documentation it states:

"Your service's API endpoints use the access token to identify the user on whose behalf Google is making the API call, and to verify that Google has authorization to access the endpoint on the user's behalf."

My fulfillment however is in Firebase Functions. So...

Do I need to get my FirebaseFunction to get the User ID from the OAuth2.0 server? Do I need to setup an OAuth2.0 server in Firebase Functions? Where does the OAuth2.0 server sit? And how do I get my Firebase Function to get the same User ID as reported by Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - you're starting with a small misconception. Actions on Google and the Actions SDK do **not** require Firebase Functions for fulfillment. Firebase Functions **do** make it easier - they provide the publicly accessible HTTPS endpoint that you need for a webhook, but if you have your own server (with valid SSL certificate) or if you want to use AWS Lambda or something similar, you can certainly do so. And if you want to use a language besides JavaScript, the JSON protocol used is documented (although sometimes not clearly).

To answer your questions:

If you need the UserID in your webhook, then yes, it needs some way to get that UserID given the access token it will be handed. But how you do this depends on how you implemented your OAuth server and token. For example:

- If you used signed JTWs as your token, then the UserID is part of the JWT and all your webhook needs to do is extract this and verify the signature and timeframe on the JWT are valid. You don't need to contact any other server to do this.
- If you're storing the tokens and corresponding user info in Firebase or in some other database or data store - just read the token from your webhook!
- You certainly can create another HTTPS endpoint you can use to validate the token and get the info from it - this is what Google does, for example.

Your OAuth server does **not** need to live in Firebase Functions any more than your webhook does. It might be a good place for it to live (along with the authentication page on Firebase Hosting), but it isn't required.

Your OAuth server can sit... anywhere. Well, anywhere public on the Internet with a valid SSL certificate anyway.

This last point is exactly what account linking is all about. You need to make sure that, when they authenticate against your server, you get the UserID that is "reported by Android", whatever that means in your context (but see my update below). Once you have this UserID, you need to make sure it gets associated against any of the tokens that you issue for this user, and you need to provide a way for your service to get this UserID from the token.

*How* you do this is up to you, and depends on the rest of your architecture and what you're trying to do with it. The Google Assistant doesn't care - it has its own notion of a UserId which is separate from yours, so to identify the user with your UserId, you'll use the token that it hands you.

**Update**

You raise a good point in the comments about the [statement](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) "The user ID on Android devices will also be the same as the user ID on a Google Home". This is true, but talks about the anonymous cookie-like UserID that is available through the Assistant platform *only* (which is why it is in the section on Anonymous User Identity). It doesn't talk about any ID that you can get through other Android apps. To associate the ID you get through other apps to the Assistant's ID, you need to use Account Linking as [described on the following page](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking).

If all you need is a consistent way to track a user that visits your Action multiple times, and you want that to be consistent on any Assistant platform (Google Home, Assistant for Android, or Assistant for iOS), then you just need to use the UserID that is provided through the API/JSON. You don't need Account Linking or an OAuth server. But this is not a Google ID or the Firebase ID, it is a anonymous UserID that is valid on the Assistant platforms only (and then, only within certain conditions if the user does not reset it).

**Update 2** To be clear about OAuth and JWTs:

You ask in the questions "Where else can I get the JWT?"

In short - you build it yourself.

Remember that, if you are providing an OAuth server, one of the things you need to do is to issue auth tokens and refresh tokens. Those tokens can be anything you want - the only criteria is that your webhook be able to take the token and, somehow, get the information it needs out of it that ties it to a user.

But *you* are responsible for putting that information in there in the first place.

So when the user logs in during account linking, you might use Firebase Authentication to log them in. Once you've done so, you can get a Firebase ID and/or a Google ID for them. (After all, they've logged into your OAuth web page - you have to know something about them.)

After they log in, you're redirecting them to some place Google has asked you to, and you're including a token as part of that. That token can be the JWT that you're creating, and in that JWT, you can include the ID information you have from their login.

(And, again... it doesn't have to be a JWT. It can be anything you want. The only requirement is that you be able to validate it and use it to get the information you need.)

Comment: This is where Google documentation is awful. https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/deploy-fulfillment suggests that you should deploy to firebase. Then https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info 
"You can anonymously identify users across conversations and devices" "The user ID on Android devices will also be the same as the user ID on a Google Home device if the all these cases are met". Well clearly not. And somewhere in Google, it refers to an OAuth2.0 section in API.AI that doesn't even exist!

Comment: Anyhow, it seems that to get the Google ID, I have to use JWT to get the Google User ID, which I presume means enabling seamless integration. Then it would be easier to keep OAuth2.0 on the same server that does the fulfillment, so as to look up the user Id by Token rather than passing a user Id back.

Comment: Fair point on their deployment examples, but https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/fulfillment-hosting does say you can deploy anywhere you want. They suggest Firebase Functions because it is the easiest for most users.

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify which ID we might be talking about. As for your solution - you don't need seamless integration - that is a step above the basic OAuth requirements, but might make things easier for your users (certainly not for you, tho). If you are using JWTs, you don't need to do lookup at all - the JWT contains the UserID. You just need to verify that the JWT is valid (as I note in my bullet).

Comment: So that anonymous id, is only for the assistant? As far as I can see you cannot access it from Google such as with FirebaseUser.getUid(). One clarification regarding JWT, that is only referenced on the seamless integration page as a way of getting the Google User Id. Where else can I get the JWT?

Comment: Correct - that anonymous UserID is just for the assistant. I've updated my answer to clarify that, I hope, and provided a more extensive update about what I mean with JWTs.

Comment: So in the same way in android we getUid(). The OAuth server is responsible for getting the user id from Google through an API call? I've seen that. So let me think... Google calls the Auth link... I presume here is where the OAuth server asks for login credentials and logs in? A little clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly. Google sends them to your login page to do the account linking. After that, you should be able to get the info you need. Hope this all helps - if so, accepting the answer and an upvote are appreciated.